# Which python canvas API has the best line quality?

Tags: python, math, graphics, tk-toolkit

I am implementing a small play tool to understand polynomial interpolation, bezier curves, b-splines...

I tried using tk, but the quality of the generated lines is pretty bad.

[image]

You can see there's a lot of aliasing and noise along the curve, and the width is not very consistent. It does its job, but I would like my lines to look more like this:

[image]

i.e much less aliased and consistent curve width.

Any suggestions?

EDIT:
For the people voting to close this question because it's "opinion based". Line quality isn't opinion based. Anti aliasing techniques are a well defined algorithm that is commonly used to improve line rendering. The screenshot shows that tk does not anti alias its lines. Thus there are objective methods to improve the quality of the line. The question is whether there are other python tools which do the effort of rendering lines properly.

Comment: Cairo is quite well-known, so maybe try [Pycairo](https://cairographics.org/pycairo/).